# Баг или моя ошибка? element.io класс, не работает корректно

Tags: javascript, vue.js, фреймворк

Использую библиотеку `element.io`
Согласно документации у них есть классы, отвечающие за сокрытие элементов на определенных брекпоинтах.

Согласно документации:

`hidden-md-and-down` - скрывать при средних и нижних окнах просмотра

```
md  ≥992px Responsive columns or column props object

lg  ≥1200px Responsive columns or column props object
```

Я устанавливаю класс `hidden-md-and-down` который по логике должен скрывать элементы при ширине 992 - 1199;

Но, при этом класс не работает на `1199px`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `hidden-md-and-down` - это класс vuetifyjs

Comment: https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/layout не только, элемент так же предоставляет этот класс

Comment: `element.eleme.io` <> `element.io` !!!
А Вы не пытались посмотреть применение стилей в инспекторе на 1199 пикселях? Вас смутило появление колонки, но не смутило отсутствие элементов другой колонки?

Comment: @SanyaH элементы колонки справа есть, они просто ушли в самый низ страницы, но, они есть